# Add BCC to email with VBA in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook

I can't figure out the correct VBA code for Outlook 2013 to add a fixed email address to the BCC field of an email while it is open for editing. I have the following code, which creates the email and then sets the BCC.

I want to add BCC to emails that I am replying to, so the message will already be in 'draft' form.

```
Sub sendcomment_click()
Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oMsg
    .Recipients.Add ("email address")
    'Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add("email address")
    'objRecip.Type = olBCC
    'objRecip.Resolve

    ' Join Email addresses by "; " into ".BCC" as string
    .BCC = "Person.A@somewhere.com; Person.B@somewhere.com"

    .Subject = "New Comment by"
    .Body = "sdfsdfsdf"
    .Display ' Comment this to have it not show up
    '.Send ' Uncomment this to have it sent automatically
End With

Set oMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

*** Update ***

I implemented the great advice from Dmitry

My code now reads:

```
Sub BCC()
Dim objRecip As Recipient
Set oMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

With oMsg

Set objRecip = item.Recipients.add("XXX@example.com")
objRecip.Type = olBCC
objRecip.Resolve

End With

Set oMsg = Nothing

End sub
```

However, when I try to run it I get an error "Run Time error '424' Object required" and it highlights the line:

```
Set objRecip = item.Recipients.Add("xxx@example.com")
```

Comment: Replace the line "Set objRecip = item.Recipients.add("XXX@XXX.com")" with "Set objRecip = oMsg.Recipients.add("XXX@XXX.com")
"

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Why is `objRecip.Resolve` needed?

Comment: Yes if you want to figure out if the name was successfully resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)`, use `Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem`.
If you set the BCC property, you will wipe out all existing BCC recipients. Use `Recipients.Add` (you have it commented out above) for each email address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define Item:

```
Sub Bcc()
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Set objApp = Application
Dim objRecip As Recipient
Dim Item As MailItem
Set Item = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
With objMsg
Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add("XXX@example.com")
objRecip.Type = olBCC
objRecip.Resolve
End With
End Sub
```