# Excel sending automatic emails reminders rgd coming due dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build an Excel sheet with due dates and corresponding email addresses. 
When it is 10 days before the due day, ideally Excel would automatically send the corresponding person an email reminding them about the due date.

I found some VBA codes online but they can only send emails to one designated emailing address.

Please could anyone kindly point out where I should be looking at? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you would like to send the same email to multiple recipients if a condition is met. I assume you are able to do this on a per-person level (if not, refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8s-jY9y220) resource), so you could simply repeat this procedure for the targeted number of recipients. Or you could also CC or BCC those other recipients, however I would suggest doing it on a personal level if time is not an issue as this adds to privacy of targeted recipients.

This post about [CC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904656/add-a-cc-recipient-to-outlook-2010-vba) and this post about [BCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365624/add-bcc-to-email-with-vba-in-outlook-2013) could help, or you could simply have a for loop for each recipient and keep your email content the same. Good luck!