# Auto BCC - Multiple Email Addresses

Tags: vba, outlook, bcc

I want to automatically BCC two email addresses.

I found this code from groovypost.com but it can only BCC one address.

```vb
Dim objRecip As Recipient
Dim strMsg As String
Dim res As Integer
Dim strBcc As String
On Error Resume Next

' #### USER OPTIONS ####
' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable
' to a name in the address book
strBcc = "SomeEmailAddress@domain.com"

Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
objRecip.Type = olBCC
If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
    strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
      "Do you want still to send the message?"
    res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
      "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
    If res = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If

End If

Set objRecip = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below adjustments should allow you to enter as many addresses as you want, provided that you split them with a semicolon `;`. It creates an array of addresses and repeats the process for as many email iterations exist.

**Side note.** I did lookup what I presume is [this article](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/how-to-automatically-bcc-in-outlook-2010/) you mentioned. I noticed that it made the strong claim that this code would *not* store the BCC record in the sender's sent box. I don't believe this to be true. Thus I'm not sure what the real advantage is to using this VBA code versus just setting up a message rule.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'make sure to separate with ;
Const strBcc As String = "first_email_Address@yopmail.com;second_email_Address@yopmail.com"

Dim objRecip As Recipient, strMsg As String, res As Long, i As Long
'On Error Resume Next

Dim theAddresses() As String
    theAddresses = Split(strBcc, ";", -1)

For i = LBound(theAddresses) To UBound(theAddresses)

    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(theAddresses(i))
    objRecip.Type = olBCC

    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
            "Do you want still to send the message?"
    
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
        "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
            
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
            End
        End If
    End If
Next i

Set objRecip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although I couldn't get this to work. I changed my macro settings and restarted my outlook and still nothing.  

Would appreciate your help again.

Comment: My bad, I'm new to SO so I hope you understand

Comment: It's all good. Thanks for accepting. Most likely your issue is with your security parameters in Outlook. Depending on your parameters. This 3 minute video gives a good summation of how to get started. https://youtu.be/zn49D4kXt-U

Comment: Oh! Also, make sure you set this procedure within and actual macro send event. First line should be  `Application_ItemSend` in it and last line should be `End Sub`. I updated my answer to reflect that. Good luck.

Comment: FYI: It does not seem possible to add a rule that add a BCC recipient - I could only add a CC recipient.  In my case, I send my outgoing mails to a backup account that I do not want to show in to the other recipients.

Comment: @le_top I'm almost positive that if you can add a cc recipient, you can add a BCC recipient. Checkout [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365624/). Let me know if that works as I've been working with on developing an add-on that indirectly relates to this.

Comment: @pgSystemTester You point to a VBA solution.  To be precise: Outlook does not seem to allow the creation of a Rule to add a BCC recipient.  The VBA code here does allow it, the UI only allows CC.